# .Net Core Binding to a Specific Model given a Specific QueryString Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I'm in the middle of refactoring an analytics api which needs to allow clients to send events as HTTP GET requests, with their "Hit" data encoded in the URL's **QueryString Parameters**.

My API's job is to recieve these events, and then place the *"valid"* events onto a queue in another part of the system for processing.

Some Hits have the same shape. The only thing that makes them different is the value of the `type` parameter, which all events must have at a minimum.

The problem I've encountered is that based on the Hit type, I'd like to be able to assume the type of each field given to me, which requires model binding. Of course. Currently, I can only find out what model to validate against after checking the value of `type` - which risks making the API excessively ["stringly typed"](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/31876/stringly-typed)

An example route would be:

GET `https://my.anonymousanalytics.net/capture?type=startAction&amount=300&so_rep=true`

Therefore, my Hit would be:

```
{
  type: "startAction",
  amount: 300,
  so_rep: true
}
```

Which, hypothetically, could be bound to the Model `StackOverflowStartHitModel`

```
class StackOverflowStartHitModel {
  public string type { get; }  // Q: Could I force the value of this to be "startAction"?
?  public int amount { get; }
  public boolean so_rep { get; }
}
```

Why am I asking this here? Well I'm normally a JavaScript developer, but everyone who I'd normally turn to for C# wisdom is off work with the flu.

I have experimented with the `[FromQuery]` attribute decorator, but my concern is that for Hits that are the exact same shape, I might not be able to tell the difference between whether it is a `startAction` or an `endAction`, for example.

Comment: what other models do you have?

Comment: I really just put in an example. We have 11 unique models at the moment, some of our events work in pairs, with matching start and end events. They're exactly the same shape, but with a different type value.

Comment: Is there a controller or something that 'gets' the data and processes it?

Comment: Yes there's a controller

Answer (score 0):

you're going to need to have a validation engine of some sort, but do not confuse this with your UI model validation. It sounds like you really have one model with a number of valid states which really is business logic.

Your model looks like this:

```
public class StackOverflowModel 
{
  public string type { get; set;}
  public int amount { get; set; }
  public bool so_rep { get; set;}
}
```

it doesn't matter what value your *type* field has and you don't need to hard-code it either, it will be captured as is and then it can be checked against valid states.

There are a number of ways to do this, that I can think of.

One option would be to create a list of valid rules ( states ) and then simply check if your input model matches any of them. One way to implement something like this could be with a library like FluentValidation. You can see an example here: [Validation Rules and Business Rules in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29866791/validation-rules-and-business-rules-in-mvc)

Another option would be to use some sort of Pattern Matching techniques like described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching

Whichever option you go with, make sure you put this validation stuff in a separate class, maybe even a separate project. You can then add tests for each rule that you have to make sure everything works. This will also keep your controller light.

You haven't given examples of valid and invalid states, but I am guessing you're really talking about variations of those 3 parameters such as, when type is "something" then amount can only be < 200 and so_rep can only be "whatever". This can be done quite nicely with the FluentValidation library.